# Replacement of temporary tables for UDF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried to create a temporary table variable, but do not know how to pass it to the procedure such that procedure could make operation insert into @temp_table

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.function1 (
@DocId int
)
RETURNS @ret TABLE 
  ( 
  [Id] int ,
  [DocId] int ,
  [EatId] int ,
  [WasteCold] decimal(5, 4) ,
  [WasteHot] decimal(5, 4) ,
  [NetMass] decimal(10, 3) ,
  [Yield] decimal(10, 3) ,
  [EmbeddedRecipeId] int)
AS
BEGIN

  CREATE TABLE #RecipeTempTable(
    [Id] int NOT NULL,
    [DocId] int NULL,
    [EatId] int NULL,
    [WasteCold] decimal(5, 4) NULL,
    [WasteHot] decimal(5, 4) NULL,
    [NetMass] decimal(10, 3) NULL,
    [Yield] decimal(10, 3) NULL,
    [EmbeddedRecipeId] int NULL)

    EXEC FullListOfProducts @DocId
    INSERT @ret
    SELECT * FROM #RecipeTempTable8
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: You can do insert into @table exec ... -kind of thing, maybe that helps. Also, UDFs can cause bad performance issues, so it might be better to come up totally different kind of solution, especially if that function would be called often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call a stored procedure from a function (by design).  Instead of doing this, just have the caller of the function set up the temp table and call the stored procedure instead, and then just use the temp table where you were using the function.  So, instead of:

```
select *
    from dbo.function1(@DocId) f
    join <some other table> t on <some criteria>
```

do:

```
CREATE TABLE #RecipeTempTable(
    [Id] int NOT NULL,
    [DocId] int NULL,
    [EatId] int NULL,
    [WasteCold] decimal(5, 4) NULL,
    [WasteHot] decimal(5, 4) NULL,
    [NetMass] decimal(10, 3) NULL,
    [Yield] decimal(10, 3) NULL,
    [EmbeddedRecipeId] int NULL)

    EXEC FullListOfProducts @DocId

select *
        from #RecipeTempTable f
        join <some other table> t on <some criteria>
```